# Export List<List<Object>> to the excel using C# in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to export a nested List to the excel. the first list of the main list should be the first column in the excel. Second list should be the next column and so on.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you share something which you have tried?

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the open-source EPPlus library. [Here](https://itenium.be/blog/dotnet/create-xlsx-excel-with-epplus-csharp/) are some examples to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using interop (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel).

You need to convert your `List<List<Object>>` into an 2-dimensional array `Object[,]`. You can either loop through your `List<List<Object>>` and copy it into an array, or you can change your code to make and array in the first place.

In this array, the first dimension needs to be the row index and the second dimension needs to be the column index. Keep in mind it will also be 0-based. So assuming we start from the top-left of the sheet `MyArray[1, 2]` will go into cell `B3`- row index 1 (the 2nd row), column index 2 (the 3rd column).

Once you have the array, all you need to do is get appropriate destination range in Excel and then set [`Range.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value)